# jest is undefined - in __mocks__ folders

Tags: jestjs, eslint

I have a file `src/api/__mocks__/api-call.js`:

```
module.exports = jest.fn(
  (method, endpointPath, queryParams, data, options = {}) => {
    if (method === 'GET') {
      return {
        data: [],
        total: 99,
      };
    }
  }
);
```

ESLint is complaining that "jest is undefined", yet this doesn't happen in my actual `__tests__` folder for some reason.

In my project's `.eslintrc.js` file, I added this:

```
env: {
  jest: true,
},
```

and this seems to have fixed it. Is this fine or is there a better way?